# Erro no cadastro php/mysql

Tags: php, javascript, html, css, mysqli

eu fiz um sistema de login e cadastro, e dentro da seção de cadastro eu coloquei uma condição, se verdadeiro cadastrar, se falso não cadastrar. Porém, por mais que no if else esteja dando true, quando eu entro no banco de dados, o cadastro não foi realizado. Como eu resolvo esse problema?

```
require_once ('connect.php');
    
    //recebendo os dados
    $user =  $_POST['user'];
    $email =  $_POST['email'];
    $senha =  md5($_POST['senha']);
    $rsenha = $_POST['rsenha'];
    $birth = $_POST['birth'];
if($connect==true){
        //inserindo os dados
    $cadastro = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Usuarios (user, email, senha, birth, cadastro) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$senha', '$birth', NOW())");
        echo "<script>
                alert('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso, basta logar!!');
                window.location.href='../index.php';
            </script>";
    }else{
        echo "<script>
                alert('Não foi possível se cadastrar, tente novamente mais tarde');
                window.location.href='../Cadastro.php';
            </script>";
    }
```

Esse é o codigo, agradeço a todos que puderem ajudar :)

Comment: Sempre que uma resposta resolver sua dificuldade marque-a como aceita, veja como https://i.stack.imgur.com/evLUR.png  e o que significa em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: Erro lógico, sua condição emitirá um alerta se sua conexão funcionar, independente de salvar os dados ou não.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_connect()` sempre retorna um objeto MySQLi. Para verificar se há erros de conexão, use:

```
$connect = new MySQLi('localhost', 'usuario', 'senha', 'db');

if ($connect->connect_error) {
   echo "Não conectou, erro: " . $connect->connect_error;
}
else {

   /* ######## e caso não haja erros faça o seu INSERT aqui ######### */
    //inserindo os dados
    $cadastro = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Usuarios ....
    ....................
    .............

}
```

Se o objetivo é verificar se o insert foi realizado então faça uso de [mysqli_affected_rows](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/mysqli.affected-rows.php) - retorna o número de linhas afetadas pela ultima consulta INSERT, UPDATE, REPLACE ou DELETE associada ao parâmetro link indicado

Answer (score 1):

Você pode validar se foi cadastrado e caso a verificação seja falsa coletar o erro do mysql.

```php
$cadastro = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Usuarios (user, email, senha, birth, cadastro) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$senha', '$birth', NOW())");
if (!$cadastro) {
   print_r(mysql_error());
}
```

Meu chute seria por causa da data, talvez você esteja mandando com o formato brasileiro, e o mysql armazena com o formato ISO (AAAA-MM-DD HH:MM:SS).

Comment: Como eu corrigiria esse erro do NOW??

Comment: Com certeza não é o `now()` o problema, deve ser com a variável `$birth`.

Answer (score 1):

Como eu havia dito em um comentário, há um erro lógico no seu código.

```
<?php

require_once ('connect.php');

        //recebendo os dados
$user =  $_POST['user'];
$email =  $_POST['email'];
$senha =  md5($_POST['senha']);
$rsenha = $_POST['rsenha'];
$birth = $_POST['birth'];
            //inserindo os dados
$cadastro = mysqli_query($connect,"INSERT INTO Usuarios (user, email, senha, birth, cadastro) VALUES ('$user', '$email', '$senha', '$birth', NOW())");
if($cadastro){
    echo "<script>
    alert('Cadastro efetuado com sucesso, basta logar!!');
    window.location.href='../index.php';
    </script>";
}else{
    echo "<script>
    alert('Não foi possível se cadastrar, tente novamente mais tarde');
    window.location.href='../Cadastro.php';
    </script>";
}
```

Ps. não testei, mas corrigi o erro lógico, entretanto teste qual é o retorno de `$cadastro` para corrigir a condição.

## EDIT 1

Tente usar este método *$mysqli->error*, dentro do seu *else* para obter os erros da sua query, ou mesmo tente executar esta query diretamente no seu MySQL Client. para ver se não há nenhum erro de sintaxe.
Tente isso:

```
else{
    echo $mysqli_error($connect);
    die;
}
```

Comment: Eu fiz a correção, a mensagem diz que não está cadastrando e realmente não está cadastrando. O erro do envio de dados está no código?

Comment: Com esse 'mysqli error' vou descobrir o problema?

Comment: Acredito que sim, a menos que haja algum outro problema que não seja com relação a consulta